# awk compare two files and print all match and non match with repetition on both files

Tags: awk

I have **two files**

```
file1
1,DAVID
22,JACK
31,SHARON
46,SUSAN

file2 
770,JACKSON
779,DAVID
776,SHARON
775,DAVID
771,SHARON
777,SUSAN
```

I **want to compare** file2 with matches in file 1
file2 can contain more than one occurrence of same name in column 2 that 
matches colum2 in file1 
the **output** i need is as below

```
779,1
775,1
771,31
777,46
```

have tried with examples given from StackOverflow but am not getting any output

**example**

```
awk -F, 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;}NR>FNR{if (a[$1]==$2)print $1,${a[$2]}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read here - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have a look at your use of `$1` and `$2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this AWK!

```
   BEGIN {
       FS=OFS=",";
   }
   FNR==NR{ # make sure we are reading from file1

       N[$2]=$1; # Asociative array, save values from file1
       next; # to force start reading file2
   }
   { # start reading from file2

       for (var in N) # for each $2 in array N
                      # variable "var" is the index of the array N
       {
           if (var == $2) # if $2 from file1 match $2 from file2
           {
               print $1,N[var];
           }
       }
   }
```

awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt

779,1
776,31
775,1
771,31
777,46

Is there any reason for the result 776.31 to not appear in your output?

Comment: for this awk file am getting this output

Comment: 771,1
775,1
776,1
777,1
779,1

Comment: i need all the matching results, i am actually trying to  compare phonenumber and name from one table with unique(specific codes and names) from another table to perfom a different operation on the results

Comment: its working, thanks a lot, kindly give a summary explanation

Comment: why not use  N[$2] instead for  N[var]?

Comment: seems like I was using column 1 as the index as opposed to column 2 for the array,thanks,now I get it

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without awk, with sort and join only:

```
join -t , -1 2 -2 2 -o 2.1 1.1 <(sort -t , -k 2 file1) <(sort -t , -k 2 file2)
#     ^    ^    ^    ^---- select which fields to display      ^    ^
#     |    |    '--------- field in common for file2           |    |
#     |    '-------------- field in common for file1           |    |
#     '------------------- field separator --------------------'    |
#                          field used to sort the file -------------'
```